# Skimage graph route to multiple destinations

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, routes, scikit-image

I want to route through an array with [skimage.graph.route_through_array](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.graph.html#route-through-array). I have one start point and multiple destination points. I am wondering if it is possible to insert the multiple destinations into the function. I know I could also loop over the function, but I am looking for something faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation you link to, it appears that `end` needs the same dimensions as `start`, which is also the same as the ndarray.  So, no, using that function you can't do what you want.  You could wrap that function in your own that, as you suggest, loops through the various endpoints.